# Is shortcode_unautop() broken?

Tags: shortcode, wp-autop

`shortcode_unautop()`  in `/wp-includes/formatting.php` is supposed to find shortcodes in a block of text and remove wrapping paragraph tags from them.

I've been having issues with paragraph tags making it through this process.

Here's the output from `var_dump($pee)`, which I placed at the very beginning of the function, i.e., the string before being processed:

```
string(353) "<p>[row wrap="true"]</p>
<p>[one_half]</p>
<p>[text_block]Fusce blandit adipiscing libero, nec bibendum diam volutpat tempor.[/text_block]</p>
<p>[/one_half]</p>
<p>[one_half last="true"]</p>
<p>[text_block]Donec fermentum diam leo, ut convallis nisl tristique ut. Ut rhoncus leo vitae tempus pulvinar.[/text_block]</p>
<p>[/one_half]</p>
<p>[/row]</p>
"
```

All wrapped in paragraph tags, as expected.

I then put `var_dump(preg_replace( $pattern, '$1', $pee ));` just before the end of the function, which gives:

```
string(346) "[row wrap="true"]</p>
<p>[one_half]</p>
<p>[text_block]Fusce blandit adipiscing libero, nec bibendum diam volutpat tempor.[/text_block]</p>
<p>[/one_half]</p>
<p>[one_half last="true"]</p>
<p>[text_block]Donec fermentum diam leo, ut convallis nisl tristique ut. Ut rhoncus leo vitae tempus pulvinar.[/text_block]</p>
<p>[/one_half]</p>
<p>[/row]
"
```

All it has done is remove the opening and closing tags from the entire block, instead of each individual shortcode. I checked the value of `global $shortcode_tags;` and all the shortcodes in my example were in it.

Is the function broken, or am I expecting too much from it? I'm pretty sure I'm not and it is supposed to remove all the paragraph tags - but I can't help thinking something else is going on, like unexpected space characters or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the function *is* broken. The issue is in trac: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14050

I am using this to solve the problem temporarily: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/14050/plugin.php . This code still fails some of the tests used, but it completely resolves the issue I described, so I will use it unless I find something practical that it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading the WordPress documentation about this function and the behaviour you are having there, is the one expected to happen.

This function clean outside of the shortcode and not inside. The regex is not checking the content of the shortcode.

EDIT:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_unautop/

> Don’t auto-p wrap shortcodes that stand alone
>
> Ensures that shortcodes are not **wrapped** in `<p>...</p>`.

Everything is said there.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this, may bee link and quote from the documentation. Your answer is flagged as low quality, but I'm not going to recommend deletion right now. As it stand, your answer is more that a comment. Please file an [edit] and add the required info to your answer. Thank you :-)

Comment: A link would be good because the inline documentation for the function simply says "Don't auto-p wrap shortcodes that stand alone. Ensures that shortcodes are not wrapped in `<p>...</p>`."