# How to prevent newline from appearing in shortcode?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I have created an extremely simple shortcode:

```
function my_shortcode($atts, $content) {
    return '<div class="block">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode('block', 'my_shortcode');
```

Then, in the Text (HTML) editor for a page, I enter:

```
[block]<h2>Test</h2>[/block]
```

I expect the shortcode to render as:

```
<div class="block"><h2>Test</h2></div>
```

But instead I get:

```
<div class="block"><br /><h2>Test</h2></div>
```

Why is WordPress inserting a `<br />`? Is there a way to prevent this behavior or at least work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<br>` tag is coming from `wpautop()`, which is one of a number of display filters added to the content via `wp-includes/default-filters.php`:

```
// Display filters
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'                       );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies',               20 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'                           );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'                 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment'                );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wp_make_content_images_responsive' );

...

// Shortcodes
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 ); // AFTER wpautop()
```

WordPress runs the `do_shortcode` filter *after* `wpautop` has has already been run on the content.

Here's a function that will remove the `<br>` tag ([source](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix/)):

```
function shortcode_wpautop_fix( $content ) {

    // Define your shortcodes to filter, '' filters all shortcodes
    $shortcodes = array( '' );

    foreach ( $shortcodes as $shortcode ) {

        $array = array (
            '<p>[' . $shortcode => '[' .$shortcode,
            '<p>[/' . $shortcode => '[/' .$shortcode,
            $shortcode . ']</p>' => $shortcode . ']',
            $shortcode . ']<br />' => $shortcode . ']'
        );

        $content = strtr( $content, $array );
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_wpautop_fix' );
```

An alternative approach is to ensure that `do_shortcode` is applied before `wpautop`. This can be accomplished by changing the priority of the display filters.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop', 99 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 100 );
```

Note that `do_shortcode` is already run at priority 11, so the goal of running it before `wpautop` is accomplished with the code immediately above.

Also worth noting, `shortcode_unautop` deals specifically with the [markup on the *outside* of the shortcode, not the inside](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178161/2807).

Comment: _Why_ does WP do this?

Comment: I added some additional notes and an alternate solution, but I do not know the specific reasoning behind the decision to run `wpautop` before `do_shortcode`. I think it's because changing priorities could break plugins. I'm also getting the feeling that a bug could involved here: [#6984](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6984), [#34722](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34722), [#19411](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19411). [Search `do_shortcode wpautop` on trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/search?q=do_shortcode++wpautop&noquickjump=1&changeset=on&ticket=on)