# Extra paragraph tags in an enclosing shortcode

Tags: shortcode, wp-autop

I have a shortcode to create columns, such that the page in the editor (text view) looks like this;

```
[two-column]<ul>
    <li>Annual statutory accounts preparation</li>
    <li>Independent Examination service</li>
    <li>Audit file preparation</li>
    <li>Gift Aid returns</li>
    <li>Payroll</li>
</ul>[/two-column]
[two-column]<ul>
    <li>Bookkeeping service</li>
    <li>Management accounts</li>
    <li>Charity Commission administration service</li>
    <li>OSCR administration service</li>
    <li>Companies House administration service</li>
</ul>[/two-column]
```

Unfortunately when on the page it appears like this;

```
<p><div class="two-column">
<ul>
<li>Annual statutory accounts preparation</li>
<li>Independent Examination service</li>
<li>Audit file preparation</li>
<li>Gift Aid returns</li>
<li>Payroll</li>
</ul>
<p></div><br />
<div class="two-column">
<ul>
<li>Bookkeeping service</li>
<li>Management accounts</li>
<li>Charity Commission administration service</li>
<li>OSCR administration service</li>
<li>Companies House administration service</li>
</ul>
<p></div></p>
</div>
```

Now I don't want to remove all `<p>` tags (by manipulating wpautop), so how do i process this shortcode.

The shortcode;

```
function column_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null)
{
   $content = '<div class="two-column">'.$content.'</div>';

   return $content;
}

add_shortcode('two-column', 'column_shortcode');
```

Comment: So you want to get rid off all the paragraph tags? please paste your shortcode function as well.

Comment: Putting the first shortcode's closing `[/two-column]` and second's opening `[two-column]` on the same line and using the solution for this question should do the trick: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239620/how-to-prevent-newline-from-appearing-in-shortcode/239622#239622

Comment: @DaveRomsey yes, that seems the simple solution but it's a question of getting the enduser to remember this. Yes, they will notice the extra space and bells will ring but it's not elegant and elegance is what we crave ;-)

Comment: it seems like what is needed is the reverse of `wpautop()`

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems someone has trod this path and there is in fact....
`shortcode_unautop()`

Job Done. It looks elegant in the editor and works in the output.

The shortcode now looks like this;

```
function column_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null)
{
   $content = '<div class="two-column">'.$content.'</div>';

   $content = shortcode_unautop($content);

   return $content;
}

add_shortcode('two-column', 'column_shortcode');
```